# How to auto close tab in Safari after the link is opened in iTunes Store

Tags: mac, itunes, safari

I want such a tab/window to auto close in Safari:

> One Moment Please.
>
> Connecting to the iTunes Store.
>
> Loading ...
>
> If iTunes doesn't open, click the
> iTunes application icon in your Dock
> or Windows Task Bar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  If you used an applescript it would also end up making Safari active. If your windows are arranged such that you can see the tab while iTunes is active you can hold down command and click on the close tab X and that will keep iTunes active while closing the tab in the background. That is about as close as you can get.

Comment: If Safari can't do it by itself, any plugin for that?

Comment: None that I can think of. You can peruse http://pimpmysafari.com/ and maybe find something. Maybe a script for http://8-p.info/greasekit/ could be written by someone.